# закрепление на канале aiogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram

как закрепить сообщение в канале с помощью бота на айограм?
перелазил все доки ваааще не пойму и что импортировать нужно

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/api/methods/pin_chat_message.html

```py
async def pin():
    await bot.pin_chat_message(...)
```